# Animate Element in Angular *ngFor Using Data Value

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Angular 12

I have a simple *ngFor, passing data to the inner element as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let taskData of sequentialTasksData; let i = index; trackBy: trackByTaskIdChange"
     [@animateTop]="{ value: taskData.locationY, params: { initialValue: taskData.locationY } }"
     [style.width.px]="3 * taskColumnWidth"
     style="position: relative; margin: 16px;">

  <div
       [style.left.px]="taskData.locationX"
       [style.top.px]="taskData.locationY"
       [style.z-index]="getZIndex(taskData.task)"
       style="position: absolute;">
    <app-tasks-diagram-sequential-task-container [taskData]="taskData"></app-tasks-diagram-sequential-task-container>
  </div>

</div>
```

My code for the `animateTop` is as follows:

```
...
animations: [
  trigger('animateTop', [
    state('initial', style({ top: '{{initialValue}}px' }), { params: { initialValue: 0 } }),
    transition('* <=> *', animate('2000ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
...
```

I have used `trackBy` so that the data objects are not completely replaced. The code for this is as follows:

```
  public trackByTaskIdChange(index: number, taskData: TaskDataSequential): string {
    return taskData.task.id;
  }
```

I am trying to get the inner div to animate smoothly up and down as the `locationY` value changes but it always jumps to its next height. Can anyone offer any advice or suggestions please?